# can I use NIO.2 for asynchronous IO from keyboard (/dev/tty) in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, nio

I'm trying to use NIO.2 asynchronous IO from /dev/tty but in the following code read does not block:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class AsyncKbd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        AsynchronousFileChannel kbd = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get("/dev/tty"),
            StandardOpenOption.READ);

        CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer> handler = new   CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer>() {
            public void completed(Integer i, ByteBuffer buffer) {
                System.out.print(new String(buffer.array()));
            }

            public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer buffer) {
            }
        };

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(80);

        kbd.read(buffer, 0, buffer, handler);
    }
}
```

I suspect that since /dev/tty is a device, file position argument (0) is equal to size (suposedly 0 too) and read does not block. Then How can I program asynchronous reads + callback handler from the keyboard?